Arch Linux wifi not available with mt7921e adapter
I'm a noob to arch and I'm getting stuck on what seems to be a basic thing. I followed the installation manual and installed and enabled NetworkManager. My internet connection works, but I can't connect over wi-fi. When I run nmcli device wifi list, I get back no results. I've made sure that wireless is not blocked. Running ip link shows wlp1s0 as up.
However, if I run nmcli device wifi list, it says that w1p1s0 is unavailable.
I was using a DE earlier on this setup and was able to connect to wifi through it. But now I removed the DE and am having issues.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!


Does iw wlp1s0 scan work? 2) What does journalctl -b -u wpa_supplicant -u NetworkManager say about the situation, if anything?


I tried rebooting and restarting network manager, and was able to get wifi working with iwd, but then my ethernet connection was having issues. So, I removed iwd and want to get this working cleanly and properly with NetworkManager alone. After all this, now for some reason the wifi interface is called wlan0 and not wlp1s0. So, when I run nmcli device status, I see that wlan0 is listed, but the status is unavailable. Running journalctl  -u wpa_supplicant gives no output since when I started using iwd.

Which Wi-Fi configuration system did you install – iwd or wpa_supplicant? Also, same questions as before.

Wow super quick response thank you! I accidentally posted the comment before I was done and didn't even have time to edit it. I added some more information in that comment. I currently have both installed but iwd is not running. I couldn't tell which fits my needs better. I'm just on a laptop that changes wifi network often.
Not sure if NetworkManager is supposed to run wpa_supplicant on its own or if that should be enabled by me to run on boot. I have tried with it enabled and with it disabled and doesn't seem to make a difference.
EDIT: btw, running iw wlan0 scan seems to work

It seems strange that wpa_supplicant isn't being started by network manager. I also noticed that the network manager config file says that it's auto-generated by network manager, but there's no actual content besides that. Is that an issue?

wpa_supplicant should be auto-started; I'm less sure about iwd. The system default wlan0 interface naming is something that iwd insists on, though. As far as I can tell, both are equally capable, but I slightly prefer wpa_supplicant for NM integration (iwd developers wanted more of a stand-alone thing that reluctantly integrates with NM). I'm not sure which config file you mean – NM touches probably a dozen (do you mean /etc/resolv.conf? or the files in /etc/NetworkManager? or the ones in /var/lib?)

I meant the /etc/resolv.conf file. I didn't have anything on my computer yet and I had some other mistakes I made during setup, so I reinstalled the whole operating system and I don't have this wifi issue any more. Not a satisfying resolution, but in my case was the easiest thing to do. Thanks for the help, though!

resolv.conf will only have content after you've successfully connected to some network, as before that NetworkManager doesn't really have any DNS server addresses to write there.
